# Match list's index based off its value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I am new to Python and working on a problem where I have to match a list of indices to a list of value with 2 conditions:

1. If there is a repeated index, then the values should be summed
2. If there is no index in the list, then value should be 0

For example, below are my 2 lists: 'List of Inds' and 'List of Vals'. So at index 0, my value is 5; at index 1, my value is 4; at index 2, my value is 3 (2+1), at index 3, may value 0 (since no value associated with the index) and so on.

```
Input:

'List of Inds' = [0,1,4,2,2]
'List Vals' = [5,4,3,2,1]
```

```
Output = [5,4,3,0,3]
```

I have been struggling with it for few days and can't find anything online that can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: How big are those lists? It's important to understand the physical size of the arrays in order to give a proper answer. One way to solve it would be to arrange the keys and values ahead of the calculation with appropriate data structures

Comment: Need to assume max length

Comment: what is the formula to calculate the output

Comment: Also is length of both lists equal

Comment: I don't have a formula for output. This is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: length of both list is equal?

Comment: you need t o provide more information'

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid I don't understand your explanation of the problem here. Please clarify your requirements. More IO examples may also help.

Comment: you need to provide more information. plus your condition 1 is confusing. and how you show in example . how the value in output is 3 not 6 at index 2 and at index 4 value is 3 not 1. a full proper statement  or how you achive output,, how you are correlating the list of index and list of value needs a proper expalation

Comment: Information is enough i am halfway through the code

Comment: @Jane go and check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List_of_Inds = [0,1,4,2,2]
List_Vals = [5,4,3,2,1]
dic ={}

i = 0
for key in List_of_Inds:
    if key not in dic:
        dic[key] = 0
    dic[key] = List_Vals[i]+dic[key]
    i = i+1

output = []
for key in range(0, len(dic)+1):
    if key in dic:
        output.append(dic[key])
    else:
        output.append(0)

print(dic)
print(output)
```

output:

```
{0: 5, 1: 4, 4: 3, 2: 3}
[5, 4, 3, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as desired. In computer science it is called "Sparse Matrix" where the data is kept only for said indices, but the "virtual size" of the data structure seems large from the outside.

```
import logging

class SparseVector:
    def __init__(self, indices, values):
        self.d = {}
        for c, indx in enumerate(indices):
            logging.info(c)
            logging.info(indx)
            if indx not in self.d:
                self.d[indx] = 0
            self.d[indx] += values[c]

    def getItem(self, key):
        if key in self.d:
            return self.d[key]
        else:
            return 0

p1 = SparseVector([0,1,4,2,2], [5,4,3,2,1])
print p1.getItem(0);
print p1.getItem(1);
print p1.getItem(2);
print p1.getItem(3);
print p1.getItem(4);
print p1.getItem(5);
print p1.getItem(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer code is

```
def ans(list1,list2):
    dic={}
    ans=[]
    if not(len(list1)==len(list2)):
        return "Not Possible"
    for i in range(0,len(list1)):
        ind=list1[i]
        val=list2[i]
        if not(ind in dic.keys()):
            dic[ind]=val
        else:
            dic[ind]+=val
    val=len(list1)
    for i in range(0,val):
        if not(i in dic.keys()):
            ans.append(0)
        else:
            ans.append(dic[i])
    return ans
```

To test:

```
  print(ans([0,1,4,2,2], [5,4,3,2,1]))
```

output:

```
  [5, 4, 3, 0, 3]
```

Hope it helps

Comment if you dont understand any step

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is sort the indexes and values in an ascending order, and then sum it up. Here is an example code:

```
import numpy as np

ind = [0,1,4,2,2]
vals = [5,4,3,2,1]

points = zip(ind,vals)

sorted_points = sorted(points)

new_ind = [point[0] for point in sorted_points]
new_val = [point[1] for point in sorted_points]

output = np.zeros((len(new_ind)))

for i in range(len(new_ind)):
    output[new_ind[i]] += new_val[i]
```

In this code, the index values are sorted to be in ascending order and then the value array is rearranged according to the sorted index array. Then, using a simple for loop, you can sum the values of each existing index and calculate the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a grouping problem. You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to build a dictionary mapping, incrementing values in each iteration. Then use a list comprehension:

```
indices = [0,1,4,2,2]
values = [5,4,3,2,1]

from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(int)
for idx, val in zip(indices, values):
    dd[idx] += val

res = [dd[idx] for idx in range(max(dd) + 1)]

## functional alternative:
# res = list(map(dd.get, range(max(dd) + 1)))

print(res)
# [5, 4, 3, 0, 3]
```